# Wait for doc to be created

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently trying to react to the creation of a document inside of firestore.

The function `createRequest` creates a doc within firestore, this triggers a firebase function which again creates a document (same id as previously created doc) inside of firestore but in another collection - **how can I wait for this exact document to be created?**

```
async createRequest(name: string, company: string, email: string, phone: string, message: string, products: any[]) {
    await this.requests.add({name, company, email, phone, message, products});
}

this.rs.createRequest(this.name, this.company, this.email, this.phone, this.message, this.products).then(() => {
    // Wait for creation of document inside of collection ('mail') with same id 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write code to add a listener (observable) for the document that's expected to eventually exist, just like any other document listener.  The listener will trigger when the document is first created, and it will receive the contents.  You must know the expected ID of the document ahead of time, which it sounds like the case here.

I suspect the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md) will help you learn about how to set up an observable on a document.

Comment: Thank you! Works for me, didn't know it was that simple. One more thing though: what about security concerns? Doing so, I obviously need to allow every user to read the collection `mail`. Indeed the user won't fetch every doc of `mail`, but still, any other doc inside of this collection would be exposed and could be abused - am I right? Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Please post a new question with your observations and concerns.  This is too complex to address in a comment.